# How to measure the divergence between two probability distribution

Tags: probability, distributions

Let consider the following probability distributions,

[image]

Dist1, Dist2 and Dist3 are the probability distribution of words over the vocabulary.
I want to find the divergence of Dist1 from Dist2 and Dist3. Can we consider the matching items for finding the divergence between two probability distributions?

Comment: None of those add up to a probability of 1, so could you explain how to interpret the numbers?

Comment: I have prepared without considering that point. Assume that they are summed up to 1. Moreover, Dist2 and Dist3 also have the long list of items with probability values summed up to 1. Actually, I want to find the divergence between top-n (say 10) items of Dist1 and Dist2 (Dist3).